# Do I have to include segment.io snippet in each web page?

Tags: segment-io

I have the snipped in the index.html but do I need to include it in all other pages?  I've tried to work around it but nothing seems to work other than including it in the header of each html file.

Comment: What do you mean by "work around it"? Web site pages are self-contained, if you want something on a page, you have to get it there somehow.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use this, the Segment analytics.js snippet must be included on every page (not necessarily the header, though that would be the easiest). The js snippet uses cookies to manage the session and state of the user, so if you want a unified picture of the user's actions on your page, it must be loaded on every page.

More details here:
https://segment.com/docs/libraries/analytics.js/quickstart/